# HTML5 progress bar with equal sized blocks

Tags: html, css

I want to design an exact progress bar given below using HTML5 and CSS3. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Progress bar with blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5LI6.png)

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It also works. I was trying it using HTML <progress> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.bar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.bar-block {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4%;
  height: 20px;
}
.bar-block:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.bar-block:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.bar-block:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.bar-block:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
  <div class="bar-block"></div>
</div>
```